# Google removing original formula on #REF! error

Tags: google-sheets

I have found that any time a #REF! error exists, google sheets permanently replaces the incorrect reference in the formula to #REF!.  Even if it was just a typo where one letter was off and all that it would have taken to fix it was to delete that extra character.. huge time waster, and also has made me lose quite a bit of work when I can't remember which reference went where in a complicated formula.

Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: Please, share your code sample or worksheet demo.

Comment: please share a sample - but also usually it only replaces your reference inside the formula when you delete the column it was pointing to, if you simply misspelled it, then it should turn gray instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference being replaced is by design. a suggestion has been submitted to Google to only put #REF! As the outputted value, instead of modifying the existing formula.

Answer (score 0):

Even though formulas display the name, Named Ranges used in formulas actually refer to the Named Range objects and not the names themselves. When you delete a named range you are deleting the object that the formula refers to. Creating a new named range with the same name is not the same object used in the formula. **To change the range that the Named Range refers to one should modify the Named Range object instead of deleting it and creating a new one.**

```
setRange(range)
```

Sets/updates the range for this named range.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#setrangerange

Comment: The script is not the problem, I already updated it before posting this issue. The problem is that refrence errors permanently alter the formulas in my cells. The script I wrote is just how I noticed it. This happens with ALL reference errors

Comment: I did not say that your code was the problem. The problem is trying to change the range that a named range refers to by deleting it and creating a new one. You must modify the existing named range. When you delete a named range your formula no longer knows what you're referring to resulting in the reference error.

Comment: I was using that as an example. I know why it was causing a reference error. That's not the issue. As i said I fixed that in my code already